# Multiple buttons on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I have an `UIImageView` on my view. Certain parts of that image, I want to use as `UIButtons`. But the problem is, Those image parts are not of in a regular shape. I haven't really tried anything. The immediate solution which came to my mind was to recognize small frames of image and put custom button over that frame. But since the image portion (button area) is not of regular shape, this concept failed.

How can I place buttons on that `UIImageView` so that particular portion(not of regular shape) of image responds to some action.

Consider the following image :

[image]

I want to place one button at the center circle which is dark. I want to place buttons in between two perpendicular lines so that a quarter of button is clickable each with different action. So, in all I have 5 buttons.

Comment: can you put some effort to explain more? I am not able to get the point. Also can't understand what you are trying to do..!!

Comment: Why don't you use custom button ? custom button is transparent !

Comment: How can I make the frame of custom button irregular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 2 options:

1. first one

   ```
   -(CGFloat)percentFromHeight:(CGFloat)percent{
   return  (CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)/100)*percent;
    }

   -(CGFloat)percentFromWidth:(CGFloat)percent{
   return  (CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)/100)*percent;
   }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self];

   //first check if the tup is in the center
   if(currentTouchPosition.x > [view percentFromWidth:45] && currentTouchPosition.x < [view percentFromWidth:55] && currentTouchPosition.y > [view percentFromWidth:45] && currentTouchPosition.y < [view percentFromWidth:55]){
      //the tup is in the center
      //Do your thing
      return;

   }

    //if this is not in the center, check other options
   if(currentTouchPosition.x > [view percentFromWidth:50]){
       if(currentTouchPosition.y >  [view percentFromHeight:50]{
            //this is the bottom left side
       else{
            //this is the top left side
       }

   }else if(currentTouchPosition.x < [view percentFromWidth:50]{
        if(currentTouchPosition.y >  [view percentFromHeight:50]{
            //this is the bottom right side
       else{
            //this is the top right side
       }
    }
   ```
2. second -

   subclass UIButton / UIImage as you prefer and use UIBezierPath to draw custom shapes in `drawRect:`, then use `[UIBezierPath containsPoint]` to check if the those is inside the path of the view/button.

Comment: Don't need `if(currentTouchPosition.x < [view percentFromWidth:50]{`

Comment: Sure, it's really nice solution for the current placement of buttons. But we still have to implement logic trying to check witch button was tapped manually, it will be damn hard for more complicated buttons blocks with non-regular shapes. Probably the way with color and alpha can be more useful.

Comment: I agree, but my answer is for this question. and he has the same color for the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527907/how-to-create-a-transparent-window-with-non-rectangular-buttons) - even the same image.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is you should use touches method to find which portion is touched(using the image frame and touchable portions' frame) and make appropriate action than adding a button.

Comment: Can you put an example. Will be really helpful.

Comment: look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647122/how-do-i-detect-a-touch-over-a-specific-area